# How to change default password reset email in djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I want to change the default email template of djoser for sending password reset email, I saw one answer in stackoverflow for changing the activation mail but i don't know how to use that for password reset email

code to change default email for activation:
**base/reset_email.py**

```
from djoser import email

class ActivationEmail(email.ActivationEmail):
     template_name = 'base/resetPasswordMail.html'
```

**settings.py**

```
DJOSER = {

   'EMAIL': {
   'activation': 'base.reset_email.ActivationEmail'
    },
}
```

how to replace this code for password reset functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default email configs of `djoser` are defined as:

```
'EMAIL': {
    'activation': 'djoser.email.ActivationEmail',
    'confirmation': 'djoser.email.ConfirmationEmail',
    'password_reset': 'djoser.email.PasswordResetEmail',
    'password_changed_confirmation': 'djoser.email.PasswordChangedConfirmationEmail',
    'username_changed_confirmation': 'djoser.email.UsernameChangedConfirmationEmail',
    'username_reset': 'djoser.email.UsernameResetEmail',
}
```

You want to change the password reset view so you need to make:

```
DJOSER = {

   'EMAIL': {
   'password_reset': 'appName.viewFileName.PasswordResetEmail'
    },
}
```

In your view you can define a `PasswordResetEmail` class. The below code is taken from djoser [repository](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/b648b07dc2da7dab4c00c1c39af3d6ec53f58eb6/djoser/email.py#L26):

```
class PasswordResetEmail(BaseEmailMessage):
    template_name = "email/password_reset.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        # PasswordResetEmail can be deleted
        context = super().get_context_data()

        user = context.get("user")
        context["uid"] = utils.encode_uid(user.pk)
        context["token"] = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
        context["url"] = settings.PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL.format(**context)
        return context
```

You can customize this class according to your purpose.